# How to access linked list more efficiently?

Tags: algorithm, linked-list

> **Problem Description**
>
> Give a string `S` and 3 operators:
>
> `Insert(ch, p)` , inserting the char `ch` to position `p`.
> `Find(p)`, finding the char at position `p` and print it to screen.
> `Transform(l,r)`, transforming the characters from position `l` to position `r` (including `l`, `r`). The **transforming** is defined as for each character `c` we apply ('a' + 'z' - c) to transform it (we use `1` for `Insert`, `2` for `Find`, `3` for `Transform`)
>
> You will get a string and several operations and just apply every operation to this string according to the definition above.

I want to solve this problem efficiently. I know that I can use linked list to store the string (every node store one single character) and this can make the operation of insertion more efficient. But the other problem is linked list is difficult to access by the index efficiently. So I want to know how can I speed up the access procedure and solve this problem using a more efficient linked list.

Comment: Why would you settle on linked lists for this? I would suggest a different data structure (such as segment tree) to handle the `transform` operation

Comment: Because I have not learned other data structure yet.

Comment: When is the result on the string tested? After every operation, or after *all* operations have been executed?